# How do I add image to the title of post?

Tags: plugins

I installed [rownling theme](http://themegraphy.com/rowling/). 
How do I add image to the title of post? Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called `Featured Images` in WordPress.

While creating a new post, on the right hand side, you will see a meta box which allows you to upload an image. The image uploaded is cropped and set as the featured image.

More about it here: [WordPress Featured Images](https://en.support.wordpress.com/featured-images/)